# Is it appropriate to say “Dächersee”?

Tags: word-choice, style, compound, poetry

I’m writing a poem and trying to find the right word to express a *sea of white roofs* – as in a city whose houses are covered in snow. I combined the nouns *Dächer* and *See,* which seemed to be the most logical choices. Does this work in a semantic sense?

Comment: Yes it does, but why did you remove the poem? It's nice *and* gives the context, which is always a good idea. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Für das Versmass wäre es vielleicht besser, das *so* eine Zeile runterzunehmen und *weisse* wegzulassen: die Häuser sind bedeckt/so dass der Dächersee. Oder bin ich da zu rigide?

Comment: In an even more poetic language, you can avoid the combination of words all together, though valid: dass der weissen Dächer See.

Answer (score 6):

Both "Dächersee" and "Dächermeer" would be comprehensible and acceptable words in the context of a poem. Outside of poetic language, a similar word, ["Häusermeer"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haeusermeer), is actually even somewhat usual.

While "die weiße Dächersee" and "das weiße Dächermeer" would accurately describe the snow-covered roofs (and possibly fit with your poem), a translation that is a bit closer to the English version you provided would also work - "die See aus/von weißen Dächern" or "das Meer aus/von weißen Dächern".

Answer (score 3):

> Dächermeer

would sound appropriate to me. I would translate **the sea** to **das Meer**, and not **der see**. **See** means **lake** when you do not us the pronoun **die**.

Comment: And ***die** See* means *the sea* (= ocean). It's actually even a touch more poetic than *Meer*.

Comment: But have you ever heard anything like **Wolkensee**, **Dächersee** etc.? **Wolkenmeer** is commonly used where I come from...

Comment: Poetic is my priority ;)

Comment: @BenNeve you know what? Take whatever fits better to the lines above and below. I think both are poetic enough :D

Comment: @WayneEra : German allows the almost unlimited generation of composed words and while "-meer" might be more frequent, there is nothing that would prohibit the use of "-see".

Comment: +1, just to do something about the -1 that i think is inappropriate.

Comment: @Burki The -1 reflected the wrong assumption that See akways means lake. The question didn't use *See (m)* but *See (f)*. Even if this answer didn't access the context, the translation *sea = lake* is over-simplified. Will happily retract my downvote if edited. I don't disagree with the suggested "Dächermeer" at all.

Comment: @Stephie It may have been female in the original version, but cureently, there is no hint in the question wether it was meant to be male or female. 
And while the answer is not exactly a good one, it still seems valid to me. Plus, i thought it might help encourage a fairly new member to stay around :-)